# Why are my CSS and Javascript files not being found by my HTML file rendered in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, css, ipad, uiwebview

Here is the code that is successfully loading the HTML into UIWebView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Player" ofType:@"html"];  
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
    if (htmlData) {  
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
        NSString *path = [bundle bundlePath];
        NSString *fullPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"Player" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:path];
        [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath]]];
    }
}
```

Here is the top part of Player.html, the HTML file is being loaded and shown, just with zero styling or javascript action:

```
<head><title>
    Course: Pegasus 1 of each
</title><link href="Content/css/jqueryui.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" /><link href="Content/css/Templates.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" /><link href="Scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" /><link href="Content/css/Pegasus.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/browser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Scripts/jstree/jquery.tree.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.carouFredSel-2.5.5-packed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.multifilterie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/pegasus.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/pegasus.quiz.js"></script>
```

Here is the Group structure, notice that the paths are relative to the root location of Player.html:

[image]

But this is what I am getting:

[image]

What should I do to make it find the files?

Answer (score 2):

The group structure you see in Xcode is not a folder structure. It's a way to organize your project workspace.
During the *Copy Bundle Resources* build phase, the files are copied to the root of your app bundle.

Check your resource dir in `~/Library/Apllication Support/IPhone Simulator/4.x.x/Applications/uid here/your.app`. You will see that there is no `Scripts` folder.

Something like

```
<script src="./browser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

should work.

---

If you really need to have a folder structure in your app bundle, select *"Create Folder References for any added folders"* when you add the `Scripts` and `Content` folders to your project resources.